# R: Removing row from data table causes kable error

Tags: r, kable

Thank you so much in advance!

I am trying to read in a csv file, strip out the first line and make it a character vector, and then print the table using kable, adding that first line back as a second-level header using kableExtra's add_header_above.

When I execute the following code, I get this error:

**Error in htmlTable_add_header_above(kable_input, header, bold, italic, : The new header row you provided has a different total number of columns with the original kable output.**

If I remove the line **table13 <- table13 [3:nrow(table13),]** the code works and the table prints, but of course the headers appear twice.

```
table13 <- read.csv("tables/table.csv", header=FALSE)
## Read the table

second_level_header <- table13  [1,]
second_level_header <- as.vector(unlist(second_level_header),mode="character")
## Remove the first line of the table and make it a character vector 

first_level_header <- table13 [2,]
first_level_header <- as.vector(unlist(first_level_header),mode="character")
## Take the second line of the table and do the same

colnames(table_13) <- first_level_header
## The second line of the table becomes the column names

table13 <- table13 [3:nrow(table13),]
# Remove the first two lines since the second line is now the column names and the first line will be the second-level header

knitr::kable(
  table_13, 
  col.names = gsub("[.]", " ", names(table_13))
) %>% add_header_above(second_level_header)
# Print the table
```

If I just print table13 to the console, I get the following. I think the problem is that the row names are being considered an extra "column," but I don't know how to get rid of them so that add_header_above sees the right number of columns.

```
                                                                      Risk Likelihood of risk Minimum
3                                            Material is late or defective                80%    100%
4 Complex airframe producibility will lead to increased manufacturing time                 25     100
5                                               GFI deliveries are delayed                 20      90
6                    Hiring and retention are affected by changing economy                 15      95
  Most likely Maximum
3        105%    130%
4         110     125
5         100     115
6         110     135
```

Answer (score 1):

Aha! Answered my own question. For whatever reason, I need to actively suppress the rownames in kable:

```
knitr::kable(
  table13, 
  col.names = gsub("[.]", " ", names(table13)), row.names=FALSE,
) %>% add_header_above(second_level_header)
```